# make error, how can I fix it?

Tags: c, makefile

I am compiling a c project, everything is OK when commands, as aclocal, .../configure, so on.
when I run "make" command, it shows an error

```
lgomp -lrt -lpthread -fopenmp
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/develop/slim/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/develop/slim/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/develop/slim/src'
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/develop/slim/lib'
Cannot execute /home/develop/slim//bin/lmntal
make[1]: *** [array2D.il] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/develop/slim/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I think "Cannot execute /home/develop/slim//bin/lmntal" is the problem. I am new at those stuff.
could anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your make file code?

Comment: make is at that place   ->>     /home/develop/slim/

Comment: As in: `cat Makefile` and post the contents here

Comment: Makefile is too much, if I posted here, is that Ok?

Answer (score 0):

If it is someone elses code, you may need to set an environment variable or something similar.

The first thing to do is check the file is there:

`ls /home/develop/slim/bin/lmntal`

Then check permissions if it is there.

`ls -ltr /home/develop/slim/bin/lmntal`

Its very hard to give advise without the make file though.

Comment: I checked, there is no  /bin/lmntal under /slim directory. I compiled this code on cygwin on windows, it is ok. now it is in ubuntu, showing that error. I set envirnment variable by using export LMNTAL_HOME=/home/develop, as instruction said

Comment: export LMNTAL_HOME=/home/develop/slim/

Comment: cannot execute /home/alim/develop/slim/bin/lmntal   now this error